# bash sed/awk/something for printing lines from match till eof except first line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Well task should be easy i guess but i failed to find the answer.

I need to find some regex in file and print all lines from first match till the end of file but the first found one.

To find and print sed/awk do the trick:

```
awk '/regex/,0'
sed '/regex/,$p'
```

But i feel pretty silly that i can't exclude first matching line from output.

Any tips? Pretty sure that shouldn't be hard. I'm just lacking of knowledge.

PS I need exactly to:

- find line matching regex
- print all lines from this regex to the end of file
- exclude first line

in one action.

Excluding line after only find-n-print action leads to more complicated solution

### Example

```
$ cat file
11 1st Cookie
12 2nd Cookie
13 1st Dinner
14 1st Candy
15 2nd Candy
16 3rd Cookie
17 1st Cake
18 2nd Dinner
19 2nd Cake
```

Find and print:

```
$ awk '/Dinner/,0' file
13 1st Dinner
14 1st Candy
15 2nd Candy
16 3rd Cookie
17 1st Cake
18 2nd Dinner
19 2nd Cake
```

What i want to get:

```
14 1st Candy
15 2nd Candy
16 3rd Cookie
17 1st Cake
18 2nd Dinner
19 2nd Cake
```

Comment: kindly post sample Input_file with expected output sample too in code tags.

Comment: Extend the sample input by adding two more lines: `18 Dinner` and then `19 Cake` and advise accordingly the expected output'

Comment: Never use range expressions (`/start/,/end/`) as they make trivial jobs very slightly briefer to code but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when your requirements get the tiniest bit more interesting (e.g. skipping a  matching line). Always use a flag variable instead (e.g. `/start/{f=1} f{print} /end/{f=0}`). Note this means you cannot use sed for it as sed doesn't support variables - just use awk.

Comment: Well basically karakfa answered with simple solution for my current case. Now i'm sitting here reading docs about variables in awk. Thank for advice, definitely need to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another alternative

```
awk 'f; /Dinner/{f=1}' file

14 1st Candy
15 2nd Candy
16 3rd Cookie
17 1st Cake
```

In general, to include either start or end pattern, there are 2x2 combinations.

```
$ awk '/Start/{f=1} f; /End/{f=0}' file
Start
1
2
3
End

$ awk '/End/{f=0} f; /Start/{f=1}' file
1
2
3

$ awk '/Start/{f=1} /End/{f=0} f' file
# or
$ awk '/End/{f=0} /Start/{f=1} f' file
Start
1
2
3

$ awk 'f; /Start/{f=1} /End/{f=0}' file
# or
$ awk 'f; /End/{f=0} /Start/{f=1}' file
1
2
3
End
```

Comment: What first "f" does?

Comment: `f` is just a variable, short for "flag", and `f;` is shorthand for `f!=0{print $0}`

Comment: oh now i get how it works. So f=0 at first encounter and then we increase it. Thanks.

Comment: `f` IS a flag but you should think of it as short for `found` as that's what the variable MEANS (that you found something in your text) as opposed to the category of variables it belongs to (flags). We do not increase flags, we only set and clear them. We increase counters which are a different category of variable.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '/Dinner/{a=1;next} a'   Input_file
```

Looking for string Dinner here, if yes then make a variable named as value 1, putting next will skip all further statements and to avoid printing that specific line which has dinner string in it. Then mentioning a means checking if a is NOT NULL then not mentioned any action here so by default print of the current line will happen.

Comment: This will skip any further record containing the word Dinner... If such a record exist.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it. :(

Comment: No prob man. I was ready to post the same solution. Tricky question by OP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a POSIX `sed` version:

```
$ sed -ne '/Dinner/{s///; :a' -e 'n;p;ba' -e '}' file
14 1st Candy
15 2nd Candy
16 3rd Cookie
17 1st Cake
18 2nd Dinner
19 2nd Cake
```

Explanation:

- `/pattern/` The desired pattern
- `s///` assuming you do not want the pattern included in the output - empty the pattern space.
- `:a; n; p; ba;`

  - a loop that:

    - fetches a new line from input (n);
    - prints it (p);
    - branches back to label a :a; ...; ba;

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -ne '/Dinner/{s///; :a;n;p;ba}' file
```